# How to type Mac Os ⌘ symbol on keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, symbols

My question is how to type this symbol:

> ⌘

**NOTE**: I´ve copy and paste it.

Comment: Hmmm, this question is more appropriate for http://superuser.com In fact, it is basically a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/158651/is-there-any-way-to-type-the-symbol-for-the-mac-cmd-key/158664#158664

Comment: well you have helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol ⌘ is called the "place of interest sign" in Unicode.

In the menu bar of a Mac OS X application (for example TextEdit) select `Emoji and symbols` from the `Edit` menu. A dialog appears.

[image: Emoji and symbols dialog]

In the search field enter "place of interest", the symbol should show up. Click and drag the symbol to some text area to enter it there. Alternatively double click it to enter it in the application whose `Edit` menu you opened.